# nine patch resources in android projects

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

I have the following case and I want to find a way to solve it, I have a base project and some other list of project use my same project as following

```
BaseProject
   |---- res
          |---- layout
                  |---- splash_screen_layout.xml
          |---- drawable
                    |---- splash_screen.9.png
```

in my list of project who use this, each project define it's own splash screen in drawable, the problem that it need me to define it as 9 patch image in all delivered projects, but I don't want to do that, I want it to load it if it is 9 patch or not

can anyone help please ?

Comment: what you want exactly?you want to use nine patch instead of splashscreen.png in all folder.

Comment: NO, I want to use either 9 patch or normal image in the child projects

Comment: then wht is your actual problem?